# Jenkins chromedriver path in selenium grid

Tags: jenkins, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

So i have Jenkins on my local machine. Selenium grid on it, and chrome plugin as well.

When i make a new configuration in the Chrome section you have to specify the chrome driver path.

Jenkins recommends:

"Path to the chromedriver executable. This needs to be set only once as it defines a global property. If you set it in multiple browser definitions, the latest will be used. If you use the Jenkins chromedriver plugin, the path will be $JENKINS_HOME/tools/chromedriver/chromedriver.ext"

So i've set it to $JENKINS_HOME/tools/chromedriver/chromedriver.ext. Problem is when i run my tests i get the following error:

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: The driver executable does not exist: /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/tools/chromedriver/chromedriver.ext

I've also google searched this issue into oblivion but I can't find an answer.

Comment: What chrome plugin are you talking about ? Can you please help share a link to it ? IMO, you dont need any chrome plugin etc., to make sure chrome automation works. You can merely download the chromedriver binary and make it available in a directory that is part of your PATH environment variable. That should basically do the trick.

Comment: You can download one in the plugin section. I did what you suggested, and now i'm getting another weird error:  Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of all elements located by .... on any tests i run, and they work fine locally but on jenkins the build always fails.

Comment: I believe that's a different issue and its not related to your original question of encountering problems with ChromeDriver not being found. I am going to update this question with my answer. It would be good if you could please help accept it. For your new issue, i would suggest that you please raise a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, you dont need any chrome plugin etc., to make sure chrome automation works. You can merely download the chromedriver binary and make it available in a directory that is part of your PATH environment variable. That should basically do the trick.